# Trying to set the potency-ratio in Instapy to a range of a specified values

Tags: python, function, github, instagram, limit

I am trying to get a python function that can accept values with a specified limit and also accept values in-between. I am working on setting the potency-ratio of instapy and it accept one value which I don't really like.potency_ratio=1.34

Answer (score 0):

You can use `potency_ratio` or not( `potency_ratio=none`, `delimit_by_numbers=True`)- will decide only by your ***pre-defined*** max & min values regardless of the `potency_ratio`

```
session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True, potency_ratio=None, delimit_by_numbers=True, max_followers=22668, max_following=10200, min_followers=400, min_following=240)
```

hope it will work for you :)